# Use of space before a unit

Tags: american-english, measuring-units, world-english

We use [space between the numerical value and unit in SI system](http://www.npl.co.uk/reference/measurement-units/si-conventions/).  Is the same principle applicable to other units e.g. Year, week etc. I mean is it 1year or 1 year? 25wks or 25 wks?  etc.

I found [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20962/should-i-put-a-space-between-a-number-and-its-unit)  but it didn't provide this answer.

Comment: Actually, even before SI units the rule is not that rigid, except perhaps in technical documents which rigidly adhere to publication standards.  It's common, eg, to write "7mm" vs "7 mm", and "5C" vs "5 C".  But in general, in every-day writing, spaces are used before non-SI units, with some exceptions.

Comment: Spacing, the use of abbreviations, and other matters related to the presentation of measurements are a matter of style. There is no single universally correct answer; you should adhere to the guidance of your editor, publication/organization, or [preferred style manual](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/2579/16052).

Answer (score 4):

It is better when you put space between them, since a number is a word and unit systems too, so 12 lbs., 100 kms., etc., is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should include spaces between numbers and units. So your examples would be "25 wks" and "1 year".